# Determine if user clicked outside shadow dom

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I'm trying to implement a dropdown which you can click outside to close. The dropdown is part of a custom date input and is encapsulated inside the input's shadow DOM.

I want to write something like:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
  if (!componentNode.contains(evt.target)) {
    closeDropdown();
  }
});
```

however, the event is retargeted, so `evt.target` is *always* the outside the element. There are multiple shadow boundaries that the event will cross before reaching the window, so there seems to be no way of actually knowing if the user clicked inside my component or not.

**Note:** I'm not using polymer anywhere -- I need an answer which applies to generic shadow DOM, not a polymer specific hack.

Comment: ...would be `window`, since I'm adding the event listener to the window.

Comment: Can we have a fiddle/example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/153047/1746830 will help!

Comment: _"There are multiple shadow boundaries that the event will cross before reaching the window, so there seems to be no way of actually knowing if the user clicked inside my component or not."_ The `event.target` would be the `host` element if clicked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try using the `path` property of the `event` object. <strike>Haven't found a actual reference for it</strike> and MDN doesn't yet have a page for it. [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-events) has a small section about it in there shadow dom tutorials though. As such I do not know the compatibility of this across browsers.

Found the [W3 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#event-paths) about event paths, not sure if this is meant exactly for the `Event.path` property or not, but it is the closest reference I could find.

<sub>If anyone knows an actual spec reference to `Event.path` (if the linked spec page isn't already it) feel free to edit it in.</sub>

It holds the path the event went through. It will contain elements that are in a shadow dom. The first element in the list ( `path[0]` ) should be the element that was actually clicked on. Note you will need to call `contains` from the shadow dom reference, eg `shadowRoot.contains(e.path[0])` or some sub element within your shadow dom.

Demo: Click menu to expand, clicking anywhere except on the menu items will close menu.

```js
var host = document.querySelector('#host');
var root = host.createShadowRoot();
d = document.createElement("div");
d.id = "shadowdiv";

d.innerHTML = `
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-item menu-toggle">Menu</div>
    <div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="other">Other shadow element</div>
`;
var menuToggle = d.querySelector(".menu-toggle");
var menu = d.querySelector("#menu");
menuToggle.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
});
root.appendChild(d)

//Use document instead of window
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  if(!menu.contains(e.path[0])){
    menu.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

```css
#host::shadow #menu{
  height:24px;
  width:150px;
  transition:height 1s;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:black;
  color:white;
}
#host::shadow #menu.active {
  height:300px;
}
#host::shadow #menu .menu-item {
  height:24px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:24px;
}

#host::shadow #other {
  position:absolute;
  right:100px;
  top:0px;
  background:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:32px;
  font-size:12px;
  padding:4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="host"></div>
```

Comment: Note, as `<div>` `width` is `width` of `window`, if click occurs to right of `<button>` `true` is logged at `console`

Comment: @guest271314, which is actually expected as that is the `div` that is inside the shadow root, so `shadowRoot.contains()` would return true for that. Added a log of the actual element to show it is the div that is inside

Comment: @guest271314, modified example to show more of what I think OP is going for. In the snippet clicking on anything except menu items will close menu. If they were to use `event.target` since it is redirected to the host you wouldn't be able to distinguish between the menu items and any other element within the shadow dom.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Now, you can use `Event.composedPath`. See the [`Event` interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event) in the DOM standard: *“Returns the item objects of event’s path (objects on which listeners will be invoked), except for any nodes in shadow trees of which the shadow root’s mode is "closed" that are not reachable from event’s currentTarget.”*

Answer (score 7):

Can't comment because of reputation, but wanted to share how it should look using `composedPath`. See [Determine if user clicked outside shadow dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369960/determine-if-user-clicked-outside-shadow-dom/69094990#comment94003671_37370083)

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  if(!e.composedPath().includes(menu)){
    menu.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted aswer

Answer (score 1):

The `event.target` of the `shadowRoot` would be the `host` element. To close a `<select>` element within `shadowDOM` if `event.target` is not `host` element you can use `if (evt.target !== hostElement)`, then call `.blur()` on `hostElement`

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var shadow = input.createShadowRoot();
var template = document.querySelector("template");
var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
shadow.appendChild(clone);

window.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
  if (evt.target !== input) {
    input.blur();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="date" />
<template>
  <select>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Comment: If there is only one layer of shadow DOM, then the event will be retargeted to the host element. But if the host element is inside another element's shadow DOM, then the event will be retargeted _twice_ before reaching the event handler on the document/window.

Sorry if I was unclear about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check the event cursor offsets against the target element:

```
listener(event) {
    const { top, right, bottom, left } = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const { pageX, pageY } = event;
    const isInside = pageX >= left && pageX <= right && pageY >= top && pageY <= bottom;
}
```