# Node.contains() doesn't include distributed content. What is the alternative

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I am making a custom element dialog box.  It is NOT modal, so needs to detect a click outside of itself to close, but I should not close when the click is inside (unless the property `closeOnClick` is set).  It uses a default `<slot>` for the contents of the dialog box. The html for it is like this (I use `lit-element` but that is not relevant to this question).

```
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
    dialog {
      position: fixed;
      padding: 10px;
      margin:0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }
  </style>
  <dialog
    id="dialog"
    @close="${this._dialogClosed}"
    @keys-pressed="${this._keysPressed}">
    <slot></slot>
  </dialog>
```

I manage multiple instances by holding a Map of instances with the z-index as the value.  When there is at least one open dialog box I have an event listener on `window` for the `click` event.  When I receive a click I use the following code to see whether to close the dialog (`this.sizingTarget` is the `dialog` element within the `shadowRoot` of my element).

```
const keys = [...openDialogs.keys()];
const self = keys[keys.length -1];
if (self.clickReady && (self.closeOnClick || !self.sizingTarget.contains(e.composedPath()[0]))) {
  //click was outside dialog (or we close on click), so close
  self.close('click');
}
```

The problem is the test `!self.sizingTarget.contains(e.composedPath()[0])` does not appear to work when the element clicked on is itself a custom element with some `<slot>` elements in it.  I found a long discussion on github about this issue and it appears they resolved it by adding `Node.isConnected` property.  But I can't work out how you are supposed to use it.

Can someone please explain how I should go about seeing if the element clicked is actually within the finally distributed nodes in my tree of elements and their (all open) shadowRoots.

Comment: So `sizingTarget` is effectively what results in `this.attachShadow(...).querySelector("dialog")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if user clicked outside shadow dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369960/determine-if-user-clicked-outside-shadow-dom)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `!e.composedPath().includes(self.sizingTarget)` works - at least it does were it worked before and the case I was struggling with above.